# Program crashing due to printf statement C

Tags: c, printf

I created a program that uses pointers and nodes for a linked list. I narrowed down the problem to the following lines of code. Every time my program reaches the printf section it crashes.

```
typedef struct book {

char title[50];
char author[50];

}BOOK;


typedef struct Node {

struct Node* next;
BOOK info;
int priority;

}node;
```

I narrowed down the problem to the following lines of code. Every time my program reaches the printf section it crashes.

```
void peek(node **head) {

    node *temp = *head;

    printf("%s by %s has been peeked.",temp -> info.title , temp -> info.author);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT :

in my main i have:
    BOOK bookDetails() {

```
BOOK b;

printf("\nEnter book title: ");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%s", b.title);

printf("\nEnter the author: ");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%s",b.author);

return b;
}
```

..and in the main(void):

```
node *queue = NULL;
case 4: peek(&queue);
        break;
```

In other cases i added information into &queue using BOOK b to link to struct book

Comment: If you never set a null-terminated character string into `title` or `author` then an crash would be expected.

Comment: You're going to need to show what you passed into `peek`. It's evidently not right.

Comment: Before using the pointer temp in the printf statement you should check that temp is a valid pointer. If temp is NULL you will get a segfault.

Comment: `peek(&queue);` with `queue` being `NULL` will crash, because this leads to a null pointer dereference. BTW you should indent your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### bookDetails()

your `BOOK b;` goes out of scope at the end of `bookDetails();`
you would be wise to ether:

- pass a pointer to a BOOK struct into bookDetails

  - you would need to change your return type to int and use it for error checking.
- dynamically allocate some heap memory inside bookDetails() with malloc() for that
  book struct.

  - requires #include  and free() when you are done with the memory.

### main(void)

what this line does `node *queue = NULL;`
in English:
allocate a new pointer on the stack to a node struct then, set the pointer to NULL.

when you pass this to peek naturally you will get some errors because you cannot deference a NULL pointer.

### struct Node and queue

you have the beginnings of a linked list structure with Node but, then I see you using this pointer to pointers queue. Unless you would like more than one linked list I would say removing the queue pointer would be a good thing to do to reduce the complexity.

### peek()

here I do like what you did to do away with the need for all those paren but on first glance `node *temp = *head;` looks like temp == head which is far from the truth

### why it is crashing recap

#### what peek says it does (in english):

- peek takes a pointer to a pointer to a node struct
- peals off the first pointer to a node
- differences that pointer (with the "->" notation)
- print to standard out.

#### substitute in what we pass to peek (in english):

- peek receives NULL(0x0)
- create a node struct pointer named temp and put NULL inside the pointer.
- Attempt to access the address 0x0 (with the "->" notation)
- segfault.

If you have any questions just ask.

Good luck :)